# How to find files older than a month using date in filename?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

This will search using file property. I know this:

```
find /home/abc -name "*.*" -mtime +30
```

But I want to find files using date appended to the filename and not the filetime. For example the files have the format `*-yyyymmdd`:

- `abcd-20180612`
- `gh24-20180512`

How do I find files older than a month using date in filename?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code.

Comment: @jww : i dont know code so i am asking question here. btw i gave sample code similar with the one i want. thanks

Comment: Use parameter expansion to isolate the date (e.g. `for i in *-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]; do datestr="${i##*-}"; ((${#datestr} != 8)) && continue; ...` then rearrange `datestr` into a format that can be used with `date -d` using *string indexes* (e.g. `fmtdate="${datestr:4:2}-${datestr:6:2}-${datestr:0:4}"` and then use `fmtdate` with `date -d "$fmtdate" +%s` to get seconds since epoch and take the difference with the current time in seconds since epoch. I'll leave it to you to put together -- if you get stuck, post your code, and ask for further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU date and awk:

```
find . -type f -name "*-????????" | awk -F '-' -v d=$(date -d "-1 month" +%Y%m%d) '$NF<d'
```

Output (example):

```
./abcd-20180412
./efgh-20180511
./wxyz-20180510
```

Comment: thanks, its working. can you please explain briefly awk part.

Comment: awk's variable `d` contains string with date one month ago (from `date -d "-1 month" +%Y%m%d`). I used `-` as field separator with find's output and then special variable `$NF` contains last column from find's output, e.g. 20180412. If value in last column (`$NF`) is smaller then value in variable `d` then awk prints complete line (find's output).